# how do you change the 2019 SSRS report to open Chrome browser instead of Internet Explore

Tags: sql, reporting-services, report, reporting

I been having some issue with internet Explore not open 2019 SSRS reports.   If I copy the report link into chrome the report open just fine.   How do I get the report to open in Chrome instead on Internet explore by default.   Is there a file associate with the report I need to change on my Windows 10 PC under setting > default apps?

Comment: you have to change the default browser on your pc

Comment: I did change the default browser under setting >apps >default apps > web browser.  It still uses Internet Explore when I run a report.

Comment: Where are you clicking on the report link?